# cakephp find all data format

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I am using following to find data.

```
$records = $this->ModelName->find('all', array('fields' => array('name','email')));
```

It gives me data in following format.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ModelName] => Array
                (
                    [name] => val
                    [email] => value1
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ModelName] => Array
                (
                    [name] => val
                    [email] => value1
                )
        )
)
```

Can I get the data in following format? If yes, how? I need following format of data array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
              [name] => val
              [email] => value1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
              [name] => val
              [email] => value1
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do

```
$new_array = Set::classicExtract($records, '{n}.ModelName');
```

Comment: where I will have to put this?

Comment: Somewhere in the controller. I forgot to mention that this returns an array, I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($records as $i => $record) {
    $records[$i] = $record['ModelName'];
}
```

Comment: If I have 1000s of records then this will take too much time to load the page.

Comment: @lakum4stackof You can test how much time will this loop take.

Comment: If you pull thousands of records, this loop will not be the bottleneck.